# How to execute cucumber feature files one after another and set time between

Tags: cucumber, saucelabs, feature-file

Hi I have two feature files and want to execute them one after another and have a specific time between the executions. Is there a parameter for example: I want execute the first test, wait for 5 minutes and execute the next one.

The reason for this is. I get timeout on saucelabs when I execute more than one feature file at a time. I only have one session available on saucelabs.
It seems that the next feature file is not waiting and tries immediately to start while the first file is executed.

Comment: Sounds more like a saucelabs problem, than a Cucumber problem. Imho there shouldn't be a dependency between feature files in Cucumber, so I doubt you can solve it there. As a workaround, could you add both features in one file? Or run both features from one runner (i.e. same session)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run different tags in 1 generic runner where in tags are related to more than 1 feature file. Using Junit with fork 2 , for running in parallel .

When trying to run get 504 gateway timeout error. when I add all the test in one feature file it works well.

Note - currently having only 1 account with 1 session in sauce labs . is that the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Write a shell script something like

```
cucumber features/feature 1
cucumber features/feature 2
```